# Laravel 5.5 json validation rule fails

Tags: json, laravel, api, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I have the following JSON posted to my laravel 5.5 application

```
{
    "code": "asdfsadf",
    "amount": "1000"
}
```

my validation rules look like this:

```
 $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'amount' => 'required|numeric|json',
            'code' => 'required|alpha_num|json',
        ]);
```

and the amount fields always pass the JSON validation but the code fields always when passing anything but int value. I could not find any solution on the web.

Comment: What's the result of `dd($request->all());`?

Comment: That is the actual validation error you're seeing? What does `dd($validator->errors());` show?

Answer (score 1):

There is no `json` validation rule that validates json on laravel. You have to build your own custom validator for that.

Something like below:

```
$data = json_decode($request->all(), true);
$rules = [
    'amount' => 'required|numberic',  
    'code' => 'required|alpha_num'
];

$validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);

if ($validator->passes()) {
    // ok validation
} else {
   //handle errors
    dd($validator->errors()->all());
}
```

Comment: The documentation suggests that there is: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-json

Comment: The rule is for the data to be a valid `JSON` string. Since the values for `code` and `amount` are not JSON data, this rule is not applicable.

Comment: @NirajShah this method is actually quiet handy for building api's.

Comment: I agree, it's very handy for building APIs, but unfortunately this rule is not relevant to this particular issue.